# ibm watson speech to text api for pure jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, ibm-cloud, speech-to-text

I am complete new to IBM Watson Speech-to-Text, and also not good at sending live audio files from html to server.

The intention is to integrate Speech-to-Text (free version) in a web application to allow for dictation and note taking. I have previously implemented the HTML speech api but the organization doesnt seem happy with its accuracy level.

So far I have only seen their demo, which seems to show that live transcription is a possibility, but I cannot seem to find sample code to use.

I primarily intend to use javascript code for the purpose (however, the application is built in ASP MVC 3).

It would be a great help if any guidance can be given or any step-by-step guide to implement speech-to-text in a web app that is free for use.

any help appreciated.

Comment: I am also looking for this, I do not want to use SDKs or stuff. I just want to do it with pure javascript because I will be implementing in 3 different scrops - react native, electron for desktop, and web. It is important i understand what is happening in each step with code. Were you able to figure this out @Abdul?

Comment: hello . apologies no. the company changed its focus for the moment and didnt continue with speech to text for the moment

Comment: Thanks @abdul for your reply. I actually figured it out. I'll post the solution here. :)

Answer (score 0):

The sample code for the Bluemix demo app is available at https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-to-text-nodejs, along with step-by-step instructions.

Comment: This is using SDK/pre-packaged. Is there a step by step which shows how to hit the endpoint with JS? I am having issues with that.

Answer (score 0):

I am also new to it. I was using javascript only from my website. I wanted to use Bluemix HTTPS endpoint (rather then WSS). The problem is that from my website, if I hit the Speech to Text API then it is considered CORS.

I read - https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/node-sdk/tree/master/examples/webpack#important-notes -  that the CORS version requires we send a token instead of a `base64_encode(USERNAME + ':' + PASSWORD)`.

So I looked up that token API here - https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/doc/common/getting-started-tokens.html - it doesn't say there though that it doesn't work with CORS, but from failed attempts and reading somehwere (reference needed) I Found out this Token API doesn't work with CORS. So I set up a PHP file on my server and put this code:

```
<?php

    $USERNAME = 'REMOVED';
    $PASSWORD = 'REMOVED';

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://stream.watsonplatform.net/authorization/api/v1/token?url=https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $USERNAME . ":" . $PASSWORD);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);

    print $result;
?>
```

Now that was getting me a token. This token lasts up to an hour I think I read on the Token API docs.

So now from javascript I can hit this endpoint on my server to get the token THEN I can use speech to text with CORS (from my website).

Here is my code:

export async function getToken() {
    const response = await fetch('my website url that gives me token);
    console.log('watson-stt::getToken - response:', response);

```
if (response.status !== 200) {
    const error = await response.text();
    throw new Error(`Got bad response "status" (${response.status}) from Watson Token server, error: "${error}"`);
}

const token = await response.text();

return token;
```

}

export async function getResults(audio, ext, token) {
    // audio - blob (web)
    // ext - type of file like "ogg" (must lower case? i dont think so but thats all i see)

```
    const data = new FormData();
    // assume blob
    const blob = audio;
    data.append('file', blob, `recording.${ext}`);

    const response = await fetch('https://stream.watsonplatform.net/speech-to-text/api/v1/recognize?continuous=true', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': `audio/${ext}`,
            'X-Watson-Authorization-Token': token
        },
        body: data
    });

    console.log('watson-stt::getResults - response:', response);

    if (response.status !== 200) {
        const error = await response.text();
        throw new Error(`Got bad response "status" (${response.status}) from Watson Speach to Text server, error: "${error}"`);
    }

    return await response.json();
}

////////////////// usage below

let stream, recorder, chunks;
async function recordAndRecognize() {   
       try {
            stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio:true });
        } catch(ex) {
            console.error('Failed to get permission to use microphone, error:', ex);
            return;
        }

        recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);
        recorder.addEventListener('stop', handleRecordingStop, false);
        recorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', handleRecordingData, false);

        chunks = [];

        recorder.start();

        setTimeout(recorder.stop, 5000); // record for 5 seconds
}

function handleRecordingData(e) {
    chunks.push(e.data);
}

async function handleRecordingStop() {
    let blob = new Blob(chunks, { type:'audio/ogg; codecs=opus' });

    let token = await getToken();
    let results = await getResults(blob, 'ogg', token);
}

recordAndRecognize(); // kick it off
```

This works with Firefox out of the box, but on Google Chrome I think I need to convert the audio first.